# remove '$' characters from a string

Tags: regex, string, lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to remove '$' signs from a string, but I am guessing it is some special char? I am extremely new to lua (just started coding in it today). From my understanding this should work and does for other chars `string.gsub(line,'$','')`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yup, that's a special character for pattern matching. you need to escape it with the `%` symbol.

```
local s = 'asdf$erer$iiuq'
print(s:gsub('%$', ''))

> asdfereriiuq  2
```

Comment: @Richard please, accept Mike's answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: General advice would be to always precede a punctuation character in a pattern with `%`. Even non-magic punctuation is guaranteed to be safely quoted by `%`. The other bit of advice is to remember that Lua patterns are not Regular Expressions. If you need the full power of a regexp, then you need to find a suitable module that wraps your favorite regexp library.